# arranging list list[i:k] from greatest to smallest and vice versa

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Hello is there an easy way to sort the elements within list[i:k] from greatest to smallest and vice versa. Thanks :).

```
start = 3
end = 8
list = [443.41, 437.74, 443.86, 445.87, 449.9, 454.27, 476.99, 526.87, 519.29, 532.66, 530.62, 539.99, 539.78, 570.02, 573.51, 574.05, 584.44, 580.0, 581.99, 579.13, 578.99, 597.77, 663.09, 704.0, 685.37, 692.93]
greatest_value = #arranges list[3:8] from greatest to smallest
smallest_value = #arranges list[3:8] from smallest to greatest
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the built-in `max` and `min` functions to get a single value, or you can use the `sorted` function if you want both.

```
start = 3
end = 8
list = [443.41, 437.74, 443.86, 445.87, 449.9, 454.27, 476.99, 526.87, 519.29, 532.66, 530.62, 539.99, 539.78, 570.02, 573.51, 574.05, 584.44, 580.0, 581.99, 579.13, 578.99, 597.77, 663.09, 704.0, 685.37, 692.93]
greatest_value = max(list[3:8])
smallest_value = min(list[3:8])
sorted_list = sorted(list)
greatest_value = sorted_list[-1] # Or sorted_list[7] to go with your example
smallest_value = sorted_list[0]  # Or sorted_list[3] to go with your example
```

All three take can take a `key` argument to specify what aspect of the item to compare against.  For example:

```
l = ['1', '20', '3']
sort_by_numbers = sorted(l, key=lambda item: int(item))
greatest_value = max(l, key=int)
smallest_value = min(l, key=lambda item: int(item))
```

This probably isn't the most readable way to deal with an array of strings, but it's purpose is to demonstrate the `key` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `lst` or something instead of `list` since it's reserved for `list` type:

```
smallest_value = sorted(lst[3:8])
greatest_value = smallest_value[::-1]
```

If you want to sort within `lst` you can easily do:

```
lst[3:8] = sorted(lst[3:8])
# For 'smallest_value', or
lst[3:8] = sorted(lst[3:8], reversed=True)
# For 'greatest_value'
```